# Is it possible to produce this broken-sphere picture with Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm currently writing an essay about the Banach-Tarski paradox.
I want to create a picture of a broken sphere, like on [this website](https://cognitivecoitus.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/the-banach-tarski-paradox/):

[image]

Does anyone know if/how this can be done using Latex?

Comment: It is possible to draw 3-D graphs in TikZ, including shaded parameterized sections of spheres, but your best bet is probably to include the graphic.

Comment: I would use several spheres and clip them with jagged outlines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this is too hacky but it is not very difficult to set up some random paths and clip them. You can change the random paths by changing the argument of `\pgfmathsetseed{42}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{ball colors/.code 2 args={\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ballA}{#1}%
\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ballB}{#2}%
\def\tikz@shading{balls}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}}%
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ballA,tikz@ballB]{balls}{\pgfqpoint{-15bp}{15bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ballA!15!tikz@ballB);
 color(9bp)=(tikz@ballA!35!tikz@ballB);
 color(18bp)=(tikz@ballA!50!tikz@ballB);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ballA!70!tikz@ballB);
 color(50bp)=(tikz@ballA)}%
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
  \draw[ball colors={red}{blue}] (-4,0) circle[radius=1cm];
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=M]
  \pgfmathsetseed{42}
  \edef\x{0}
  \loop
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\u{\x*2}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x*2+1}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x*60+20*(rnd-0.5)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\bA}{\x*60+10*(rnd-0.5)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rA}{0.1+0.8*rnd}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\bB}{\x*60+30+10*(rnd-0.5)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{0.1+0.8*rnd}
   \ifnum\x=0
    \edef\lsta{\a}
    \edef\lstb{\bA,\bB}
    \edef\lstr{\rA,\rB}
   \else
    \edef\lsta{\lsta,\a}
    \edef\lstb{\lstb,\bA,\bB}
    \edef\lstr{\lstr,\rA,\rB}
   \fi
   %  
   \edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1} 
  \ifnum\x<6\repeat
  %
  \edef\x{0}
  \loop
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\u{\x*2}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x*2+1}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\z{mod(\x*2+2,12)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{{\lsta}[\x]}
   \ifnum\x=5
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{{\lsta}[mod(\x+1,6)]+360}
   \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{{\lsta}[mod(\x+1,6)]}
   \fi
   \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5*\a+0.5*\b:0.5)}]
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\a:1) arc[start angle=\a,end angle=\b,radius=1]
      -- plot[samples at={\z,\y,\u},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]})
      -- cycle;
     \path[ball colors={red}{blue}] circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{scope}
    \draw (\a:1) arc[start angle=\a,end angle=\b,radius=1]
      -- plot[samples at={\z,\y,\u},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]})
      -- cycle;
   \end{scope}
   \edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1} 
  \ifnum\x<6\repeat
  %
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0.17)}]
   \begin{scope}
    \clip plot[samples at={0,...,6},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
    \path[ball colors={red}{blue}] circle[radius=1cm];
   \end{scope}
   \draw plot[samples at={0,...,6},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-0.17)}]
   \begin{scope}
    \clip plot[samples at={6,...,11,0},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
    \path[ball colors={red}{blue}] circle[radius=1cm];
   \end{scope}
   \draw plot[samples at={6,...,11,0},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=R]
  \draw[ball colors={red}{blue}] (4,0) circle[radius=1cm];
 \end{scope}
 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Once done, one can play with it, or convince oneself that the pieces match (which is in some way against the paradox).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{ball colors/.code 2 args={\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ballA}{#1}%
\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ballB}{#2}%
\def\tikz@shading{balls}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}}%
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ballA,tikz@ballB]{balls}{\pgfqpoint{-15bp}{15bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(tikz@ballA!15!tikz@ballB);
 color(9bp)=(tikz@ballA!35!tikz@ballB);
 color(18bp)=(tikz@ballA!50!tikz@ballB);
 color(25bp)=(tikz@ballA!70!tikz@ballB);
 color(50bp)=(tikz@ballA)}%
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \pgfmathsetseed{28}
  \edef\x{0}
  \loop
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\u{\x*2}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x*2+1}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x*60+20*(rnd-0.5)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\bA}{\x*60+10*(rnd-0.5)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rA}{0.1+0.8*rnd}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\bB}{\x*60+30+10*(rnd-0.5)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{0.1+0.8*rnd}
   \ifnum\x=0
    \edef\lsta{\a}
    \edef\lstb{\bA,\bB}
    \edef\lstr{\rA,\rB}
   \else
    \edef\lsta{\lsta,\a}
    \edef\lstb{\lstb,\bA,\bB}
    \edef\lstr{\lstr,\rA,\rB}
   \fi
   %  
   \edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1} 
  \ifnum\x<6\repeat
  %
  \foreach \RR in {0,0.04,...,1}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    %
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=M]
     %
     \edef\x{0}
     \loop
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\u{\x*2}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x*2+1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\z{mod(\x*2+2,12)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{{\lsta}[\x]}
      \ifnum\x=5
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{{\lsta}[mod(\x+1,6)]+360}
      \else
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{{\lsta}[mod(\x+1,6)]}
      \fi
      \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5*\a+0.5*\b:0.5*\RR)}]
       \begin{scope}
        \clip (\a:1) arc[start angle=\a,end angle=\b,radius=1]
         -- plot[samples at={\z,\y,\u},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]})
         -- cycle;
        \path[ball colors={red}{blue}] circle[radius=1cm];
       \end{scope}
       \draw (\a:1) arc[start angle=\a,end angle=\b,radius=1]
         -- plot[samples at={\z,\y,\u},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]})
         -- cycle;
      \end{scope}
      \edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1} 
     \ifnum\x<6\repeat
     %
     \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0.17*\RR)}]
      \begin{scope}
       \clip plot[samples at={0,...,6},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
       \path[ball colors={red}{blue}] circle[radius=1cm];
      \end{scope}
      \draw plot[samples at={0,...,6},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
     \end{scope}
     \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-0.17*\RR)}]
      \begin{scope}
       \clip plot[samples at={6,...,11,0},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
       \path[ball colors={red}{blue}] circle[radius=1cm];
      \end{scope}
      \draw plot[samples at={6,...,11,0},variable=\t] ({{\lstb}[\t]}:{{\lstr}[\t]}) -- cycle; 
     \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    %
    \path (-2,-2.3) (2,2.3);
   \end{tikzpicture}}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you only love `TikZ`... If only...

Comment: @NguyenVanJustonlyChi I actually do not think that Ti*k*Z is ideal for this task, with MetaPost and Asymptote one could just split the path into subpaths that correspond to the intersection segments, and shift these paths much more elegantly. (Splitting paths into intersection segments is also possible with Ti*k*Z, but it is not very easy to pick the wanted ones.) However, I do not understand the other tools well enough, and this post is tagged `tikz-pgf`. I actually would love to see a solution with the other tools.

Comment: Excellent...Very beautiful.

Comment: Thank you very much!!